# Can Partner user create reports?

Tags: partner-portal

I want a Partner User to create reports. Is it possible anyhow.  User having a profile cloned from Partner profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user must have the Create and Customize Reports permission in order to create a new report, but since the permission is not available for partner users you will be out of luck.  The only access you can give them is to view.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I am looking for a way where a Partner user can create the reports with the Partner profile only . Let me know if there is any workaround for this. Thanks.